# View Ephemeral Notebook Jobs on Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm currently using [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html) to view all job runs on our azure databricks host. I can view all created jobs, but I cannot view ephemeral notebook jobs (jobs created through the *dbutils.notebook.run* command inside of a python notebook). Runnning the following command:

```
databricks runs list
```

Produces the following result:

[image]

I know I can get information on a ephemeral run because when a specify an ephemeral jobs job_id:

```
databricks runs list --job-id 4819
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

I know that if I tie the notebook to a job and then run the job inside of a notebook that I'll be able to view the runs, but I'd prefer a method without having to do that.